# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting a IllegalArgumentException error: Invalid URL error when trying to display a dice image. The error is occurring in the playRound method the line where the error is marked by a comment. This error occurs when the user hits the roll dice button which will display the dice that the user has rolled. My images are located in my Images folder of my project. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Netbeans project Structure

[image]

I have printed out whether file exists to see if my url is correct. It shows that the path exists but I am still getting a Invalid URL Error.

```
        private static void playRound() {
    playerIndex = 0;
    maxScore = 0;
    hitButton.setDisable(false);
    standButton.setDisable(false);
    blackJackRoundPlayer = blackJackRound.get(playerIndex);
    playerName.setText("Player Name: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getPlayer());
    currentBalance.setText("Player Holdings: " + Integer.toString(blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings()));
    betAmountLbl.setText("Wager Amount: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundWager());
    currentBalance.setText("Current Holdings: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings());

    hitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        roll1 = rollDice();
        roll2 = rollDice();
        //validate file exists
        System.out.println("Dice Roll 1: " + new File(".\\src\\blackjack\\Images\\dice-six-faces-" + roll1 + ".png").exists());
        System.out.println("Dice Roll 2: " + new File(".\\src\\blackjack\\Images\\dice-six-faces-" + roll2 + ".png").exists());
        System.out.println("dice-six-faces-" + roll1 + ".png");
        dice1View.setImage(new Image(".\\src\\blackjack\\Images\\dice-six-faces-dice-six-faces-" + roll1 + ".png"));/*error occurs on this line*/
        dice2View.setImage(new Image(".\\src\\blackjack\\Images\\dice-six-faces-dice-six-faces-" + roll2 + ".png"));

        blackJackRoundPlayer.addToRoundScore(roll1 + roll2);

        roundScore.setText("Round Score: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore());
        //player score is 21 or break
        if (blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore() >= 21 && playerIndex <= blackJackRound.size()) {
            playerIndex++;
            if (playerIndex <= players.size() - 1) {
                if (blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore() > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore();
                }

                blackJackRoundPlayer = blackJackRound.get(playerIndex);
                playerName.setText("Player Name: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getPlayer());
                currentBalance.setText("Player Holdings: " + Integer.toString(blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings()));
                betAmountLbl.setText("Wager Amount: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundWager());
                currentBalance.setText("Current Holdings: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings());
                roundScore.setText("Round Score: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore());
            } else {
                hitButton.setDisable(true);
                standButton.setDisable(true);
                determineWinner(maxScore);
            }

        }
    });

    standButton.setOnAction(e -> {

        playerIndex++;
        if (blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore() > maxScore) {
            maxScore = blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore();
        }

        if (playerIndex <= players.size() - 1) {
            blackJackRoundPlayer = blackJackRound.get(playerIndex);
            playerName.setText("Player Name: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getPlayer());
            currentBalance.setText("Player Holdings: " + Integer.toString(blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings()));
            betAmountLbl.setText("Wager Amount: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundWager());
            currentBalance.setText("Current Holdings: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getPlayer().getCurrentHoldings());
            roundScore.setText("Round Score: " + blackJackRoundPlayer.getRoundScore());
            //determine winner
        } else {
            hitButton.setDisable(true);
            standButton.setDisable(true);
            determineWinner(maxScore);
        }

    });
}




 Dice Roll 1: true 
 Dice Roll 2: true
 dice-six-faces-4.png
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or
```

Comment: You'll find the reason your code fails in the duplicate question. For resources it would be better to access them via resource URL though: `new Image(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/Images/dice-six-faces-dice-six-faces-" + roll1 + ".png").toExternalForm())`

Comment: Thanks for your help fabian. When I try  it that way it says non static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: In `static` methods you can replace `getClass()` with `ClassName.class` where `ClassName` is the class containing the method.

Comment: Aright thanks. Now I am getting a nullPointerException even though it is finding that the image exists.

error log:
Dice Roll 1: true
Dice Roll 2: true
dice-six-faces-1.png
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at blackjack.GUI.BlackJackGUI.lambda$playRound$1(BlackJackGUI.java:186)

Comment: I solved the issue putting file: in front of the file path fixed the issue. Thanks again for your help.